# Import .numbers spreadsheet into R

Tags: r, import, spreadsheet

Is there any function that will allow import of a .numbers (Apple's spreadsheet program) file into R? I can import a .xlsx file using `read.xls` from `gdata` package. But using `read.xls` does not work on .numbers files.

Comment: According to a quick web search this software should be able to create  xls files. Possibly it can also export data as text files?

Comment: Thats what Ive been doing, but would prefer to keep everything as .numbers files

Answer (score 3):

No formal package and [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland)'s right in that you may be way better off doing a `File->Export->CSV` to get the data out. If you only have one table you need — e.g.:

[image]

you need then could *could* get away with selecting the cells and using `pbpaste`:

```
dat <- read.csv(pipe('pbpaste'), sep='\t')
dat
##       A   B
## 1     4 456
## 2     5 346
## 3     5 345
## 4    34 345
## 5     4 345
## 6    45 345
## 7    46 345
## 8  3456 345
## 9   678  34
## 10  568  34
```

That's not scaleable tho.

Alternatively, Numbers has regained AppleScript support and it has an `export` call, so—in theory—it's be dirt simple to create a folder action or command-line script to take one or more `.numbers` files and put them to CSV. That could also be a way to write a thin 'shim' module or function in R that would just do that behind the scenes (e.e. `read.numbers("myfile.numbers", table=1)` which would then take that Numbers sheet and export the first table to a CSV file then use `read.csv` to read it in).

**UPDATE**

To that end, here's a modification of a script by (@plang)[https://stackoverflow.com/users/1982991/plang] from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10845335/1457051) that works with the most recent version of Numbers. Getting this into a `read.numbers()` function/package isn't too difficult, but not something on my radar to build as it needs to handle way too many edge conditions in how Numbers saves CSV documents from documents with multiple tables/sheets.

The current AppleScript dictionary for Numbers would make it very possible to do an open and read table directly from a script (that will still IMO need to use the `pbpaste` hack since I don't think there's an R<->AppleScript bridge). It could be done through the Java<->AppleScript bridge but that seems like overkill given the small population that needs to use Numbers docs directly.

I still recommend the conversion of the script (below) to a folder action and dragging Numbers files you need to use in R to it for batch conversion.

```
# - input: Numbers input file
# - output: CSV output file
#
# Attik System, Philippe Lang
#
# Orig from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10845335/1457051
#
# Creation date: 31 mai 2012
# Modification date: 07-Apr-2014 by @hrbrmstr
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
on run argv
    # We retreive the path of the script
    set myPath to (path to me)
    tell application "Finder" to set myFolder to folder of myPath

    # We get the command line parameters
    set input_file to item 1 of argv
    set output_file to item 2 of argv

    # We retreive the extension of the file
    set theInfo to (info for (input_file))
    set extname to name extension of (theInfo)

    # Paths
    set input_file_path to (myFolder as text) & input_file
    set output_file_path to (myFolder as text) & output_file

    log input_file_path
    log output_file_path

    if extname is equal to "numbers" then
        tell application "Numbers"
            open input_file_path
            export document 1 as CSV to output_file_path
            close every window saving no
        end tell
    end if
end run
```